# What would be the most appropriate code to return the amount of available RAM in linux? (C++)

Tags: c++, linux

The code I'm currently using provides three different measurements of available RAM memory on a Linux system. However, I've noticed that each measurement occasionally returns a different value, and these values are often below the actual amount of available memory in the system. This inconsistency has raised questions about which of the three results is the most appropriate or accurate representation of the available memory.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <cmath>
#include <sys/sysinfo.h>


using namespace std;

int checkMemoryAvailable()
{
    ifstream meminfo("/proc/meminfo");
    string line;
    double totalMem = 0.0;
    double freeMem = 0.0;
    double buffersMem = 0.0;
    double cachedMem = 0.0;

    while (getline(meminfo, line))
    {
        istringstream iss(line);
        string key;
        double value;
        iss >> key >> value;

        if (key == "MemTotal:")
        {
            totalMem = value;
        }
        else if (key == "MemFree:")
        {
            freeMem = value;
        }
        else if (key == "Buffers:")
        {
            buffersMem = value;
        }
        else if (key == "Cached:")
        {
            cachedMem = value;
        }
    }

    double availableMem = freeMem + buffersMem + cachedMem;
    double memoryMIP = trunc(availableMem / 1024) / 1000;

    //cout << "\nTotal installed RAM memory: " << totalMem << " kB" << endl;
    //cout << "RAM memory available for use: " << memoryMIP << " GB\n" << endl;

    return static_cast<int>(memoryMIP);
}

int checkMemoryAvailable2() {
    // Get system information about memory usage
    struct sysinfo info;
    if (sysinfo(&info) != 0) {
        cerr << "Error: Could not get system information." << endl;
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    // Calculate the amount of available memory
    long long totalMemory = info.totalram * info.mem_unit;
    long long usedMemory = (info.totalram - info.freeram) * info.mem_unit;
    long long availableMemory = totalMemory - usedMemory;

    // Print the results
    //cout << "\nTotal memory: " << totalMemory / (1024 * 1024) << " MB" << endl;
    //cout << "Used memory: " << usedMemory / (1024 * 1024) << " MB" << endl;
    //cout << "Available memory: " << availableMemory / (1024 * 1024) << " MB" << endl;

    double memoryMIP = (double)trunc((availableMemory / (1024 * 1024)) / 1000);
    return (int)memoryMIP;
}

int getAvailableMemory3()
{
    struct sysinfo memInfo;
    if (sysinfo(&memInfo) == -1)
    {
        cerr << "Failed to retrieve system memory information." << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    long long totalMem = memInfo.totalram * memInfo.mem_unit;
    long long freeMem = memInfo.freeram * memInfo.mem_unit;
    long long buffersMem = memInfo.bufferram * memInfo.mem_unit;

    long long availableMem = freeMem + buffersMem;
    double availableMemInGB = static_cast<double>(availableMem) / (1024 * 1024 * 1024);
    return (int)(availableMemInGB);
}


int main()
{
    int availableMemory = checkMemoryAvailable();
    cout << "Available memory (Method 1): " << availableMemory << " GB" << endl;
    availableMemory = checkMemoryAvailable2();
    cout << "\nAvailable memory: (Method 2): " << availableMemory << " GB" << endl;
    availableMemory = getAvailableMemory3();
    cout << "\nAvailable RAM memory: (Method 3): " << availableMemory << " GB" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure they're not just returning different results due to being run at different times? How much difference are you seeing between the results?

Comment: Do you ever see it that you get `EXIT_FAILURE` GB printed? :)

Comment: Mine doesn't print Exit_Failure. It may be that the difference is for this reason, but the first method returns me 2Gb more than the second and third.

Comment: you should check that `iss >> key >> value` succeeds

Comment: There are a number of components that go into the amount of RAM available (if you search there is a post on it on this site -- though I don't have a link). For example, `BUFFERS:` represent memory that was used (and shown as used), but is no longer used and is available for use by the memory manager to hand out RAM to your program. There are other smaller pieces as well. You can read the kernel doc on memory for the description of each if you can't find the link on this site.